# What is limiting the visibility of this function?

Tags: javascript

In the following two pieces of code `bar` is not visible outside of the expression of which it is part (IIUC).

```
function foo(a) {
    console.log(a);
}

foo((function bar(){ return 'bam'; }()))
console.log(bar); // ReferenceError
```

...and

```
const { foo = (function bar() { return 'bam'; }())} = {};
console.log(bar); // ReferenceError
```

As far as I understand it `LexicalEnvironments` define scope in JavaScript. And the `OuterEnvironment` reference defines the scope chain.

Is it correct to say that there is a `LexicalEnvironment` made specifically for this expression based on its lexical position? And that this `LexicalEnvironment` is preventing  bar from being visible in the outer `LexicalEnvironment`?

Or is there some other mechanism hiding the function named `bar`?

The [spec explicitly states](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments) that LexicalEnvironments are associated with modules, global object, functions, blocks, and catch clauses.

Comment: For a named function expression, the name only exists inside that function, not outside.

Comment: `bar` exists in the scope of `foo` and is not hoisted, so it's scope bound. You cannot access `bar` outside of `foo`

Comment: Based on these comments named function expressions like this use the existing function `LexicalEnvironment`. I wonder about things like default value calculations for destructuring assignment .